# Is there any way that the first character of a text box is either '+' or '-' by default

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

I have a text field on my form actually its like GMT time. I want the users to 
enter integers like '+5' '+6' or '-6' or '-5' etc.

I want to make it easy for users so that they don't have to write '**+**' or '**-**' by there self. There should be by default option of '**+**' or '**-**' as first character in text field.

*I saw some solutions like making a simple drop down in front and user can select from there which will automatically appear in text box.*

But i want to make it more easy if some other easy solution is there.

will prefer using HTML5 but if not than jquery will be fine..

Comment: What is more easy for user than dropdown?

Comment: i mean there will be a drop down and a text box together which will look awkward i guess.. i want a single tex tbox if its possible

Comment: The how will you decide `-` or `+`?

Comment: That's y i posted the question

Comment: when you select on the dropdown the value of the selected option will go to the textbox.. is that right?

Comment: @user3113490 actually this is the right solution as i told i saw it earlier but can we manage it using only 1 textbox?

Comment: you can do it on a multiple textbox... so you want if you have 3 textboxes and if the user select the `+` sign it will all appear in 3 boxes?

Comment: How are you going to decide if it should be `+` or `-` by default?

Comment: @AbhishekUmrao the first character can be '+' or '-' of this text field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var num = 0; 
        $('#txt1').keydown(function(e){
              num += 1;
            if (e.keyCode > 36 && e.keyCode < 41)  {

                if(num % 2){
                 $('#txt1').val('+');

                }else{
                   $('#txt1').val('-');
                }

                }

            });          
    });
</script>

<input type="text" name="txt1" id="txt1" />
```

Comment: it will be a drop down. which will allow me to select only actually i want to integrate it with my text field

Comment: we can do that using jquery or javascript.. wait a bit

Comment: will it be in a single text box (the drop down option plus writable area)?

Comment: its working perfect.. but can we do it by using single textbox with some functionality.if not i will be implementing this.

Comment: i think u didnt get me in above coment below question. actually iam saying can we avoid using Dropdown and just do something on textbox to achieve same functionality

Comment: hmm.. I don't know if you can do that with only single textbox... if you do that on single textbox I can't think of any jquery event that lets the users choose "+/-" sign..

Comment: Conclusion is that i cannot do it without dropdown

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77606/discussion-between-ammar-ul-hassan-and-user3113490).

Comment: this will solve your problem.. just press arrow up or down... for the `+/-` sign to show.. =) don't forget to upvote.. =)

Comment: well its fine but how will the user come to know about this plus or minus on arrow up down?

Comment: well you can put a label beside the textbox... lol.. and I've made some changes... =) so that if you press arrow keys the `+/-` sign will show up and you can still input some numbers there. =)

Answer (score 1):

you could try this:

```
var $input = $('#input');
var defaultChar = '+';
$input.val(defaultChar);

$input.on('keyup', function(event) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var currentText = $this.val();
    currentText = getDigits(currentText);

    $this.val(defaultChar + currentText);
});

function getDigits(text) {
    var digits = text.match(/[+-]?(\d*)/);

    console.log("text = " + text);
    console.log("digits = " + JSON.stringify(digits));

    if(digits.length > 1) {
        return digits[1];
    } else {
        return 'did not contain numbers';
    }
}
```

[here is the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/marcelortega/bpznLbgk/)

EDIT: added dropdown to select defaultChar.

Javascript:

```
var $input = $('#input');
var $defaultCharElem = $('#defaultChar');
var defaultChar = $defaultCharElem.val();
$input.val(defaultChar);

$defaultCharElem.on('change', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    defaultChar = $this.val();
    $input.val(defaultChar + getDigits($input.val()));
});

$input.on('keyup', function(event) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var currentText = $this.val();
    currentText = getDigits(currentText);

    $this.val(defaultChar + currentText);
});

function getDigits(text) {
    var digits = text.match(/[+-]?(\d*)/);

    console.log("text = " + text);
    console.log("digits = " + JSON.stringify(digits));

    if(digits.length > 1) {
        return digits[1];
    } else {
        return 'did not contain numbers';
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<select id="defaultChar">
    <option value="+">+</option>
    <option value="-">-</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="input" value="" />
```

[Here is the new fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/marcelortega/bpznLbgk/1/)

Comment: but in case of minus as our starting character what will we do ??

Comment: change default char to minus. you could also bind the above code to a dropdown to change the defaultChar.

Comment: conclusion is that i can not do it with out dropdown